# How to make a filter on my own field in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I added a boolean field is calculated from the time like this:

```
def is_active(self):
    if self.inactive_to and self.available_until:
        if datetime.date.today()>=self.inactive_to and datetime.date.today()<=self.available_until:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif self.inactive_to:
        if datetime.date.today()>=self.inactive_to:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif self.available_until:
        if datetime.date.today()<=self.available_until:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
is_active.short_description = 'Available'
is_active.boolean = True
```

But if I try add it to "list_filter" I get error "'RealtyAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_active' which does not refer to a Field."

I can avoid it, or add in model fild that will be calculated automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not enough attentive, here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/ is a description of how to add your own filter (from 1.4)

Answer (score 2):

admin is not a field which subclassed from django.db.models.fields.

That's what `'is_active' which does not refer to a Field."` is saying..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). Your code is for adding a new column in the `list_display` but your title and error message refer to `list_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The Django ORM cannot find a database field named `is_active`, because it's a python function. The Django admin does not enable sorting or filtering by python function returned results.
However, as you said, you can add a field to your model which contains the value you want, and then add it to `list_filter`.